# grammar about come here vs coming here

Tags: grammar

it's a real privilege to be able to work in this kind of mountain environment and to enthuse about it to other people and attract them to **come here**.

it's a real privilege to be able to work in this kind of mountain environment and to enthuse about it to other people and attract them to **coming here**.

How is both sentenses different? , which one is correct in terms of come here or coming here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the verb *attract*, as it's used here, means "to cause to come to a place" ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/attract)). (It's a little like "draw" in "*to draw the crowds.*") So "*to attract them to come here*" means "*cause them to come here to come here*." You're drawing them here twice!

You could just say, "and attract them here," or "and attract them to the area." Or maybe rewrite it a little and say, "...and interest them in coming here" or "...and interest them in visiting the area."